# how to update the cube to get the mdx working fine

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

I have been trying to get the ValueR column of the following query through the MDX but instead getting ValueW as output of the MDX

```
select 
exp(Log(sum(MTMROR)+ 1 ))-1 as ValueW,
exp(sum(Log(MTMROR + 1)))-1 as ValueR
from 
Temp_Performance
where Rundate in ('2015-03-01','2015-03-02')
```

MDX written for the above query is

```
With 
Member [Measures].[LogValuePre]
as ([Measures].[MTMROR] + 1)
Member [Measures].[LogValuePre1]
as VBA![LOG]([Measures].[LogValuePre])
Member [Measures].[LogValue]
as VBA![Exp](Sum([Measures].[LogValuePre1]))-1

select 
{
    [Measures].[LogValuePre],
    [Measures].[LogValuePre1],
    [Measures].[LogValue]
} on 0,
{
    [Dim Company Fund].[Company Fund Id].&[1274] 
    //* {[Dim Time].[Date].&[2015-03-01T00:00:00] : [Dim Time].[Date].&[2015-03-//02T00:00:00]}

} on 1
from 
(
    select {[Dim Time].[Date].&[2015-03-01T00:00:00] : [Dim Time].[Date].&[2015-03-02T00:00:00]} on 0 
    from [DSV_Cube]
)
```

[MTMROR] measure has the aggregate function Sum. What i can get from this behavior is MDX is first aggregating the result and default aggregation function is Sum. When i try to see the value with more granular data by having the date dimensions on the row (un-commenting the date dimension) i get the correct log and exp log values. Its showing the correct value as date dimension is most granular level in the fact table. While trying to get the data at less granular level(Fund level), getting the sum function applied automatically.
    If i set AggregateFunction to none in the cube structure, i get null as the output.
   How could i apply the log function before the sum function in the [MTMROR] measure?

Thanks

Comment: The fact on which the measure `MTMROR` is built is related to which dimensions out of the above and how?

Comment: @SouravA: Fact MTMROR is related to two dimensions [Dim Company Fund] and [Dim Time]. Both are related to fact as the regular relationship.

Comment: Can you let us know on some sample results please?

Comment: @SouravA: [Measures].[MTMROR] has aggregate function set to SUM. Desired operation is exp(sum(log( 1 + mtmror)))-1. I tried to achieve with calculated members in above query. Grain of the fact is CompanyFundId ,Date. When i try to get output at less granular level which is CompanyFundId,  [Measures].[MTMROR] gets added before the calculated members work on the [Measures].[MTMROR]. This is kind of expected behavior. When aggregate function is changed to None then [Measures].[MTMROR] returns null unless fact grain is defined in the MDX. I want Calculated members to perform at less grain data.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the aggregation type as `None` and add a calculated member in cube as below:

```
SCOPE
    (
    [Dim Time].[Date].[All],
    [Measures].[MTMROR]
    );


This = 
SUM
 (
 NonEmpty
 (
  [Dim Time].[Date].MEMBERS, 
  [Dim Company Fund].[Company Fund Id].CURRENTMEMBER
 )
 * [Dim Company Fund].[Company Fund Id].CURRENTMEMBER,
 [Measures].[MTMROR]
 )
```

What this does is whenever the date level granularity is not in context(i.e. the `ALL` member is in), it finds all the dates for this fund ID and for the combination of that fund id and the dates, it sums it up(effectively keeping the `AggregationType` as SUM). If instead, a date IS on axis, it behaves normally and displays the value.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If the aggregation type HAS to be `SUM`, add one more measure in the measure group and just keep it's value as `LOG(MTMROR + 1)`

Use that in your calculation.

Comment: I think my words were not good to illustrate the problem. AggregationFunction is Sum.While both fund and date are on axis,most granular data is fetched so nothing is there to get added. Sum works fine with only date on the axis. With only data on the axis i need to perform the Log (MTMROR + 1). What exactly happening is Log(Sum(MTMROR) + 1) . Member with AggregationFunction has the low solve order so Sum gets performed before Log operation on calculated member. Most of the time i need SUM first behavior and at few instances need the Log behavior. Is to possible to perform Log first??

Comment: So you mean 'None' aggregation type is not a possibility and it absolutely has to be 'Sum'?

Comment: If we set 'None' aggregation type then we have to give FundId,Date on axis to show MTMROR number. I think with None aggregation type,we have to all the attribute on the axis which defines the grain of the fact.